# Using data-clipboard-target

Tags: zeroclipboard

I've been trying to implement codes second item from the below address
https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard/blob/master/docs/instructions.md#text-to-copy

The below example looks like very nice. However I spent 8 hours and I couldn't be successful.
http://zeroclipboard.org/#demo

Actually I need to use ZeroClipboard for two different elements. I can accomplish if I use for just one elements. Otherwise every time second constructed element's copy operation works.

```
<body>

      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="client_id" class="control-label">Client ID:</label>
         <button id="copy_id" data-clipboard-target="client_id">Copy ID</button>
         <input id="client_id" class="form-control" >
     </div>        
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="client_id" class="control-label">Client ID:</label>
         <button id="copy_secret" data-clipboard-target="client_secret">Copy Secret</button>
         <input id="client_secret" class="form-control" >
     </div>     

     <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>

     <script>
                // I think I should write some codes here but which codes?
     </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours I found a way. I think this is the one way if a user wants to use with two different HTML elements.

### Sample code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tr">
<body>
  <div>
    <button id="copy_id" type="button" class="clip_button" type="button">
        copy id value
    </button>                           
    <input id="client_id" type="text" readonly>
  </div>

  <div>
    <button id="copy_secret" type="button" class="clip_button">
      copy secret value
    </button>
    <input id="client_secret" type="text" readonly>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zeroclipboard/2.2.0/ZeroClipboard.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(function() { // jquery main function

       // fill inputs using fictive data
       $("#client_id").val("ClientID112")
       $("#client_secret").val("ClientSecretWordSShh")

       // ***** copy to clipboard operations **********************
       var client = new ZeroClipboard( $('.clip_button'), {
           moviePath: "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zeroclipboard/2.2.0/ZeroClipboard.swf"
       } )

       client.on("copy", function(e) {
       var clipboard = e.clipboardData;
       if(e.target.id == "copy_id")
           clipboard.setData("text/plain", $("#client_id").val())
       else
           clipboard.setData("text/plain", $("#client_secret").val())
       })
       // ***** end of copy to clipboard operations ****************

    }) // end of jquery
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This really helped. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

for use data-clipboard-target attribute, the only thing to do in the event

client.on("copy", function(event) {  ... }

is to use

**event.relatedTarget**

this is how in jquery reads the target id to read.

so a little example:

**HTML SECTION**

```
<button class="clip_button" id="my-button_text" data-clipboard-target="clipboard_text">Copy to Clipboard</button>
<button class="clip_button" id="my-button_textarea" data-clipboard-target="clipboard_textarea">Copy to Clipboard</button>


<input type="text" id="clipboard_text" value="Clipboard Text"/>
<textarea id="clipboard_textarea">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</textarea>
```

**JAVASCRIPT SECTION**

var client = new ZeroClipboard( $('.clip_button') );

```
  client.on( 'ready', function(event) {
    // console.log( 'movie is loaded' );

    client.on( 'copy', function(event) {
        event.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', event.relatedTarget.innerHTML);
    } );

    client.on( 'aftercopy', function(event) {
      console.log('Copied text to clipboard: ' + event.data['text/plain']);
    } );
  } );

  client.on( 'error', function(event) {
    // console.log( 'ZeroClipboard error of type "' + event.name + '": ' + event.message );
    ZeroClipboard.destroy();
  } );
```

i hope this can help

this worked for me with ZeroClipboard 2.2.0